# DRF - How to change serializer.PrimaryKeyRelatedField's filter lookup key with condition?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I am trying to change `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField`'s filter lookup key based on other boolean field on serializer but I could not be successful. PrimaryKeyRelatedField filtering by `pk` key by default. In some condition (if `condition` field on serializer sent as `True`), I just want to change that filtering key with another field on related model's field like `remote_id`.

```py
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    condition = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
    model_pks = serializer.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Model.objects.all(), many=True)
```

I tried to create new field which is inherited from `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and override `get_queryset` method (not sure to override correct method) so far but I could not access `condition` and `model_pks` fields values.

```py
class CustomPrimaryKeyRelatedField(PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        # model_pks = sent model_pks
        if condition:
            return queryset.filter(remote_id__in=model_pks)
        return queryset.filter(id__in=model_pks)
```

Also, I tried to use `SerializerMethodField` instead of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` like;

```py
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    condition = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
    model_pks = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_model_pks(self, value):
        pks = self.initial_data.get('model_pks', [])
        if value.get('condition', False):
            return Model.objects.filter(remote_id__in=pks)
        return Model.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
```

It's provide changing lookup key based on `condition` but this time I could not access `model_pks` values with `serializer.validated_data`.

Is there any way to make conditional lookup key filtering using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally succeeded on my own question with creating custom primary key field. On this custom field I just recreated `to_internal_value` method and accessed `condition` value with `self.root`.

```py
class CustomPrimaryKeyRelatedField(PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        condition = self.root.initial_data.get('condition', False)

        if self.pk_field is not None:
            data = self.pk_field.to_internal_value(data)
        try:
            if condition:
                return self.get_queryset().get(remote_id=data)
            else:
                return self.get_queryset().get(pk=data)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.fail('does_not_exist', pk_value=data)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('incorrect_type', data_type=type(data).__name__)
```

I am not sure that this is the best way to deal with kind of this issues. But it solves my problem for now.

Comment: But, this is only for post request right, beacuse I am trying to filter a primary key related field and show only relevant object of it  in the browsable API page, and facing some issue. Why haven't you implemented `to_representation`.

Comment: @ManishShah yes. this serializer used with only post requests therefore we do not take any action with to_representation method.